# Weird Messages by executing Process.Start command

Tags: c#, excel, system.diagnostics

We have a project which creates an Excel file and save it in Network shared drive and after that it opens up that file,
application works fine but I get a weird messages.
Consider the following piece of codes

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
....
xlsAppClass = new Excel.Application();
Process excelPID = GetExcelProcessId(xlsAppClass);

//
// All codes generate and save the excel file...
// and return the filePath which is located in Network Shared drive.
//

xlsWorkBook.Close();
xlsAppClass.Quit();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlsSheets);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlsWorksheet);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlsWorkBook);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlsAppClass);
if (excelPID != null) excelPID.Kill();

// When program reaches this line of code excel file created, saved and Excel process killed
// I checked the TaskManager, nothing's there.
```

Then I opens up the generated file via the following code

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);
```

at this moment System opens up the file but I get the following message as well which I couldnt figure it out WHY
"Microsoft Office Communicator 2007 is already running"

Comment: And if you type that file path name in the Windows Run dialog or at the command line, does Excel start and load the file?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I restarted the PC, and issue resolved!